# useMap is rendered 4 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to import useMap() hook provided by "@vis.gl/react-google-maps" library and it's rendered 4 times. Can i know why is that so?

removed StrictMode. i've one file only and this lines.

```
    <APIProvider apiKey="">
        <Map />
        <MyComponent />
      </APIProvider>
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const map = useMap();
  console.log("component rendered");
};
```

Comment: Maybe you have <StrictMode> in the main.js?

Comment: I know what to do. I have to load the api centralized way to control when it's loading and when it's already loaded.  as useMap is trying to load at first it's null and than it loads thats why it re-renders.

Comment: Are you referring to the `console.log("component rendered");` which is an unintentional side-effect directly in the function body of the component? Yeah, this isn't an accurate measure of then the component is rendered to the DOM. Move the console log into a `useEffect` hook so it's one log per render cycle. Other than this, it's unclear what any additional issues are. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and more complete details.